# Difference Avro Vs Cloudevent Vs AsyncAPI | Best fit for Schema evolution and naming convention in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, cloudevents, asyncapi

I am using confluent schema registry.

What is the difference between Avro Vs Cloudevent Vs AsyncAPI

What is the best fit for Schema evolution and naming convention in kafka ?

Can we use different schema types for different topics based on requirement ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, looking at the other answer, AsyncAPI is not a library.

CloudEvents is a specification for describing your event data
AsyncAPI is a specification for defining API of your application that is part of event architecture. In simple words, it is like OpenAPI for REST

They both can coexist https://www.asyncapi.com/blog/asyncapi-cloud-events/

Avro is a binary data format for serialization and deserialization, like JSON or XML.

All of those can work together, your Avro can be encapsulated in CloudEvents enveloped and a number of them can be listed in AsyncAPI file that describes your application.

Comment: Do you have any example in Java and Kafka Client using CloudEvents, AsyncAPI, and Avro?

Answer (score 1):

CloudEvents is a specification. It does not prescribe what form the data should take

Avro is a binary data format for serialization and deserialization

AsyncAPI is library in a way that the code runs

---

You could use **AsyncAPI** to send non-blocking **Avro** records (that get registered to the Schema Registry) that adhere to the **CloudEvents** specification...

---

> Can we use different schema types for different topics based on requirement ?

Are you having problems with this? That is how the Schema Registry works by default

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a look at [AsyncAPI or CloudEvents? Both My Captain!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p9RyClgYhE) for a detailed explanation and example of how to use them together.